# Start of tomcat failed

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, netbeans, netbeans-7

I am facing issue to start my tomcat server in netbeans. I am getting error when I click on start button

```
"Starting of tomact failed, check whether  the /Application/NetBeans/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/bin/catalina/sh and related scripts are executable."
```

For more details please check screenshot
[image]

Comment: Does `/Application/NetBeans/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/bin/catalina.sh` exist?

Comment: Yes it is exists. I have checked it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should run from the command line / shell if you can though I realize you want to run from Netbeans in this case.

Also make sure that all your `.sh` scripts are executable (do a `chmod`) because otherwise they cannot be called.

Lastly, make sure you have the right permissions to run the scripts.

Once you are beyond these checks, you'll possibly get other error messages e.g. your `JAVA_HOME` or your `CATALINA_HOME` are not set. These will be easy to fix.

#### EDIT

To run Tomcat from the terminal,

- go to your Tomcat folder (either `TOMCAT_HOME` or `TOMCAT_HOME/bin`).
- Make sure all `.sh` scripts are executable (`chmod a+x *.sh`)
- run `startup.sh`: .`/startup.sh` or `bin/startup.sh` (depending on whether you are inside `TOMCAT_HOME` or inside `TOMCAT_HOME/bin`)

Comment: David I am not good in scripts but I have tried to follow your instructions. Please have a look below commands which I tried in terminal

Chandras-MacBook-Pro:bin chandraprakash$ chmod a+x *.sh
Chandras-MacBook-Pro:bin chandraprakash$ startup.sh: ./startup.sh
-bash: startup.sh:: command not found

Chandras-MacBook-Pro:bin chandraprakash$ run startup.sh: ./startup.sh
-bash: run: command not found

Comment: Oh its working now I have tried sh startup.sh

Thanks david. for your kind help.

Answer (score 5):

You can make `catalina.sh` runnable by executing following command in terminal

```
chmod 755 <your tomcat location>/bin/catalina.sh
```